# Testcafe-hammerhead erorr reset-guard.ja:27

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I am getting an error sometimes when I run testcafe

/opt/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/connection-reset-guard.js:27
    throw err;
    ^

Comment: Try to explain your question properly.

Comment: In witch way ? I need tags to explain my question more properly, Can you help ?

Comment: `+ /opt/testcafe/bin/testcafe-with-v8-flag-filter.js 'chromium:headless --no-sandbox' -e -q --reporter xunit test int
/opt/testcafe/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/connection-reset-guard.js:27
    throw err;
    ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:864:14)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results`

Answer (score 3):

This problem was already fixed in `testcafe@0.23.1`.
The commit with the fix - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/commit/a5821a69f2d53799b1028ce459b03b1af662eb79